# Cannot exctract any resources in my jetpack compose project R.string does not show

Tags: android-resources, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to extract a string resource in my app but when I press `R.string` it shows `cannot find string resource` .

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're importing the correct R class .
In your R.string make sure the R is from the name of the project
For eg:

If your project name is `tutorial project` make sure when you press R it is of `com.example.tutorialproject` type.